# Openings that are devastating for the opponent if they don't know the theory

Tags: opening, opening-traps

I'm a 1200 on chess.com and people at my level play random openings. They usually don't blunder and the games often go to boring, equal endgames.

I have been loving the Vienna game because most of my opponents fall for the Vienna gambit (because of not knowing the critical d5 move)!

What are some other openings that could destroy the opponents quickly if they don't know the critical moves/theory, for both White and Black?

Comment: Playing 1.e4 as white works well if you want sharp play, and as black you could look for lines in the sicilian/pirc/king's indian defense for black. Generally, if you want sharp play you should look for openings that create imbalances (i.e., not completely symmetric like the french exchange variation). At your level you're going to waste your time if you spend too much time on learning specific variations though, so learn the basic opening principles and look at how players like Morphy punished opponents who violated those principles.

Comment: @Scounged thanks ill research more on these!